# How Run Spring boot .war/jar file eclipse? What is de Url of a REST API from a .war?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat

First what I want to achieve:
 -I want to be able to deploy and run/debug Spring-Boot services on Eclipse IDE with WTP Tool plugin (Tomcat).

I've tried to run it as standalone service in the shell and works fine.

But when I generate the .war file, in not able to find a way to "associate" the .war generated(maven) with the tomcat server that I have on eclipse and debug the code.

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>NantiAPI</groupId>
    <artifactId>NantiAPI</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
<!--        <start-class>ramon.jansen.gomez.nanti.springboot.api.Application</start-class> -->
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- <plugin> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>3.1</version> -->
            <!-- <configuration> -->
            <!-- <source>1.8</source> -->
            <!-- <target>1.8</target> -->
            <!-- <fork>true</fork> -->
            <!-- <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\javac</executable> -->
            <!-- </configuration> -->
            <!-- </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also my "main"

```
 @SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Any help will be welcomed, and any requested info.

---

Edited:

What is de Url of a REST API from a spring-boot .war?

Currently I can deploy my project into tomcat in Eclipse, I had my project as Maven and configured it as Faceted Form, Web Dynamic(Configure options)(it generates de .war needed).

But now i not able to request the REST through Postman, it returns a 404, if I run it as a java application, it works.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, it is *very strongly* recommended to use a jar with a `main` method instead of using a war, which requires external infrastructure and all sorts of complications.

Comment: But im trying to automatized my developments, so if i want to integrate this service for jenkins to automatically deploy de jar/war into my tomcat server...
How im suppose to do so, if im doing only with jar?

Comment: You don't use Tomcat and just run the jar. Some people like using Docker, I like Cloud Foundry (which generates the image for you).

Comment: Well im trying to build REST API microservices with spring-boot with my own(home made) server, to consume them in an Android App.  Iv'e made a bad choice with spring boot for that scope @chrylis? Or what im missing? I read about docker/Cloud Foundry, but for now I want to have my home hosting or it isn't worth?

Comment: So are you asking about how to do this in Eclipse, or in Jenkins?

Comment: @nitind in Eclipse, with the tomcat plugin, to access via postman to the REST API.
About jenkins, is just a pipeline that builds de GIT repository into a .war that is deployed in a **tomcat** server.(ins't importat I think)

Comment: Using Spring Boot is a great choice for that kind of application, but it's much simpler to use the executable jar instead of deploying into an external Tomcat.